# Restoring MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to restore a MySQL database for a while now

```
root@lsstreetwars1:/home# service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 9609
root@lsstreetwars1:/home# mysql -u root -p forum > server.sql
Enter password:
```

It's just stuck here, and the database is only a few megabytes.

Comment: Do you have a backup of your server.sql file?  The above command looks like it probably wiped it!

Answer (score 3):

you made a mistake by the direction of shell-redirect. Try this:

```
mysql -u root -p forum < server.sql
```

Comment: Hopefully he didn't already wipe the contents of his server.sql file by trying it the other way.